# Empty Object or Class/Empty Type using Templates

Tags: c++

I have written a program that has a class with a constructor and destructor written with couts and cins.

The class contains a run() function which I am using as my menu. From the menu, I want to have the user select the option to 1. Test the constructor (creates an instance from the class) and 2. Test the destructor (exits the menu and destructs at the end of main).

Here is my dilemma.

In main() in order for me to use the run() function, I have to create and instance of the class. However, I am using templates. ie. `Class<classType> classTypeRun`.

In order for me to create an instance to be able to use run() I have to specify a classType, and this will call the constructor, which I do not want. I only want the constructor to run when the user selects it from the menu.

What is the most efficient way to go about this?
Should I create an inheritaned class just for the run() function?

Comment: So this `run` function is `static` and independent of the template parameters?

Comment: Why is `run()` a member function?  Given your proposed requrements (you want the constructor to run when the user selects (1) and the destructor when the user selects (2), that is not possible with a member function of a template class as you've found out.

Comment: K-ballo: Yes it is.

Chad: I've found that out, yes. It is member function strictly because I set it up to be as such. However, since I added a menu that I want only to explicitly call the constructor/destructor I am asking of the best, fastest and most efficient way to achieve it. Mind you that I am by no means advanced in C/C++.

Comment: @SD likely the option I provided in my answer below is the simplest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `run()` a free function, like this:

```
  template <class T>
  class MyT
  {
  public:
     MyT(const T& v) : val_(v) {}

     const T& get() const {return val_;}
  private:
     T val_;
  };


  int run()
  {
     int opt;
     cout << " 1) Create\n 2)Destroy\n";
     cin >> opt;
     cin.ignore();
     return opt;
  }

  int main()
  {
     int opt = 0;
     std::auto_ptr<MyT<int>> t;

     do
     {
        // call the menu...
        opt = run();

        // if the user selected option 1, and we haven't
        // already constructed our object, do so now.
        // (Calls MyT<int>())
        if(opt == 1 && !t.get())
           t.reset(new MyT<int>(10));

        // if the user selected option 2 and we have 
        // already constructed our object, delete it now
        // (Calls ~MyT<int>())
        if(opt == 2 && t.get())
           t.reset(0);
     }
     while(2 != opt);
  }
```

Comment: What do the auto_ptr and reset elements do? These are new to me. I will read up on them now.

Comment: A `std::auto_ptr` is a smart pointer.  It manages the lifetime of the object (`MyT<int>`) that we have dynamically allocated.

Comment: Very nice. I wish I had known about auto_ptr and its member functions sooner! Let me implement this and I will report back.